# Appending <li> item to <ul> with TS

Tags: html, typescript, list, inline

I have been trying to append "Avocado" to this list but then I get the error message

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')*

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html >
    <html  lang="de">
    <head >
    <title >Am I Loaded ?! </title >
    <script>
        const element = document.getElementById("list")
        const elementText = document.createTextNode("Avocado")
        element.appendChild(elementText);
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Meine Obstschale</h1>
    <ul id="list">
        <li >Apple </li >
        <li >Pear </li >
        <li >Orange </li >
        <li >Banana </li >
        </ul >
    </body >
    </html>
```

What am I doing wrong here, please?

Comment: your script is running before your dom has loaded - either move it to the end of the page or put it in document ready function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that you are trying to invoke the member function `appendChild` on a null object. This does not work because there are no member functions on a null object. In your code you only invoke `appendChild` once, which means that `element` is that null object. Knowing this, you can see that `getElementById` returned that null object. Either your ID does not exist or it is not loaded yet.

tl;dr; You are running that Javascript before the elements of your page are loaded.
You can place your script right before the closing `body` to circumvent this.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html >
    <html  lang="de">
    <head >
    <title >Am I Loaded ?! </title >
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Meine Obstschale</h1>
    <ul id="list">
        <li >Apple </li >
        <li >Pear </li >
        <li >Orange </li >
        <li >Banana </li >
    </ul >
    <script>
        const element = document.getElementById("list")
        const elementText = document.createTextNode("Avocado")
        element.appendChild(elementText);
    </script>
    </body >
    </html>
```